# how to add JAVA_HOME variable to PATH variable in ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I want to get some variable from one file and use it in other shell files.
for this purpose I create two files as below.

I have two sh files.

1. setenv.sh
2. Setup.sh

**content of setenv.sh :**

```
 #!bin/bash

export JAVA_HOME=/home/jre
```

**content of Setup.sh :**

```
. ./setenv.sh

echo $JAVA_HOME

export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

java Copy
```

**when I run the Setup.sh file it gives the following output:**

```
/home/jre

java not found
```

So can you please help me to solve this issue.
thanks

Comment: Does your `/home/jre` folder exist and actually contain a `bin` folder, in turn containing the `java` binary?

Comment: Try running `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java Copy` from `setup.sh` script

Comment: @Mena Yes the folder is exist and have all the required files.

Comment: @anubhava tried but not working. thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: What does `ls -l /home/jre/bin/java` show you?

Comment: @anubhava if i changed export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin to export PATH=$PATH:/home/jre/bin then its working fine.

Comment: Try export PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin

Comment: @Morad

I have change as per your suggestion as below:

#!/bin/bash
. ./setenv.sh

echo $JAVA_PATH
echo $PATH
export PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_PATH}/bin
echo $PATH

java Copy


Now Output is:

/home/jre

/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

/bin/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/jre

java not found

Comment: It's strange that your PATH has /home/jre in the end of it instead of /home/jre/bin. What happens when you add "TMP=${JAVA_PATH}/bin; echo $TMP" to your script?

Comment: Does `setenv.sh` have DOS line endings by any chance?

Comment: It seems that it replace the  /usr (First output) to /bin (Second output) as you can see at the starting point of both the output.

Comment: The first line of setenv.sh seems to be a space, I guess a formatting issue. Please change. (File is sourced, so it doesn't matter)

Comment: @WalterA Thanks for your suggestion, yes it was a formatting issue. Many Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) of the two scripts: as Walter A says, please remove the beginning space from the first line and check the endofline (LF vs. CRLF) for each file (dos2unix tool could help).

In addition, and to use java executable directly from your $PATH entry, maybe you need to add shebang of the `Setup.sh` script too.

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is the problem: `. ./setenv.sh`
The `./setenv.sh` path is relative to the current directory and is not relative to the setup.sh script itself.

In setup.sh, please either refer to setenv.sh using absolute path or use
`$($(basedir $0)/setenv.sh)`